# Is wordpress core still jquery-dependant?

Tags: jquery, core

As per the title. I don't know where to find this information but, is wordpress Core still jquery dependant? I generally use my own custom themes, so I do not need jquery for the themes, and I can check every plugin I use for jquery dependencies.

But still I don't know if I really can safely quit using jquery. I mean frontend only, not admin.

Did any of you already do it?

Comment: The admin still uses jQuery in places but the front end has never been jQuery dependent, it’s always been up to themes whether or not to use jQuery. Some plugins may require it, but that’s a choice by the plugin, not a requirement.